# Error from folder name when using Jupyter

Tags: python, macos, jupyter

I'm new, please be gentle.

I am taking a bootcamp to learn something new and skill up my career, so...yeah.

When running the following in my notebook, I get the error. (*see screengrab above*)

df = pd.read_csv(r/Users/.../02 Data/Original Data/orders.csv, index_col = False)
—————
Cell In[4], line 1
df = pd.read_csv(r/Users/.../02 Data/Original Data/orders.csv, index_col = False)
^
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers

,...where on Mac OS, ECC/(*all the relevant folder names*) and 02 Data is where it gives me an error. I really don't want to change the names of all my folders to prevent the error.

Is the solution to enter '0o2 Data' as that part of the path? Will that 'see' or interpret the folder name correctly?

I really do apologize for the n00b question, I'm just trying to get my head around some new things here.

Tried that; didn't work. Any solution where I don't need to rename would be helpful.

[code and first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPmSx.png)
[Error after tryong 0o2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sRBy.png)

Comment: You're missing quotes around the path.

Comment: ...ugh. Thanks. 

df = pd.read_csv(r'/User......orders.csv', index_col = False)

Apparently fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`df = pd.read_csv(r"/Users/.../02 Data/Original Data/orders.csv", index_col = False)`